# Cardinalidade em Banco de Dados - Relacionamento Um para UM

Tags: banco-de-dados, relacionamento, cardinalidade

estou estudando banco de dados, e no momento além das definições de banco, tipo de modelos estou vendo Cardinalidade!
Estou com dúvidas nesse exercício abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minhas dúvida são as seguintes

> Como eu identifico a a `origem` e o `destino` desse relacionamento?

Pois para mim a origem seria Boleto e o Destino Pagamento..

> Também queria saber se meu pensamento sobre `cardinalidade` está correto!

A `cardinalidade (0,1)` para o boleto e `(1,1)` para o pagamento... Estou certa?

Mas a resposta do exercício é :

`Origem` (min=1, max=1) e `Destino` (min=0, max=1)

Ou seja- Aparentemente: o pagamento como Origem e o Boleto como destino!

Comment: As formas de representar as cardinalidades mudam bastante, você teria a legenda da linha tracejada ? nr_boleto provavelmente é uma chave primária, mas vl_juros ? qual seria o tipo ?

Comment: Então não tem legenda! O exercicio apenas pede para dizer o relacionamento:Identifique a cardinalidade mínima e máxima da origem e do destino do
relacionamento referente ao MER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há um erro de conceito na postagem.

O termo "**cardinalidade**" refere-se a *quantidade de instâncias* de um objeto associadas a outro. Normalmente é utilizado quando tratamos de um diagrama de objetos.

O termo correto seria "**multiplicidade**", o qual define as *quantidades mínima e máxima às quais um objeto pode estar associado*. Este termo sim é utilizado em um modelo de banco de dados ou em um diagrama de classes.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

[image: Exemplo de Diagramas Equivalentes]

Agora respondendo as questões:
Em um modelo desse tipo, não existe a ideia de origem e destino, pois não há um fluxo de informação; o que existem são relacionamentos entre entidades. Assim, o que está representado no diagrama é o seguinte:

"A entidade t_boleto está associada a um único t_pagamento (1..1), enquanto que um t_pagamento está associado a um único t_boleto também (apesar de não declarado, quando não há indicação de multiplicidade, entende-se que o valor é 1..1, conforme o metamodelo da UML)."

A resposta dada ao exercício não me parece correta, mas parece que realmente considera o t_pagamento como Origem e t_boleto como Destino e não sei qual foi a base para isso.